# Getting LLVM and Clang from downloaded sources and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, llvm

I just downloaded the sources of LLVM and Clang as compressed files.

The files I have so far are:

- cfe-3.5.0.src.tar
- compiler-rt-3.5.0.src.tar
- libcxx-3.5.0.src.tar
- libcxxabi-3.5.0.src.tar
- llvm-3.5.0.src.tar

I need to configure LLVM and Clang using Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013.

I ask this question because the tutorials I have consulted so far uses svn, but having the sources from compressed files I not have a clear vision of what should be the directory tree in order to cmake work properly.

Comment: Do you have a Visual Studio 2013 (Express Desktop) varion installed on your machine?

Comment: compiling is not much trouble, you download all, put every thing in the right place (ex: cfe-... need to go to llvm\tools and be named clang. You could see the CMakeList.txt files for hints like this, then using cmake you could generate the VS solutions and compile. The problem normally is using the compiler later with the MS std library (the support have improve much but almost any middle size program with std, some boost, would break the compilation). I've had better success compiling in windows with MinGW.

Comment: @NetVipeC Does this probably answer the question? I'm not experienced using CLang with the MSVC compiler as backend.

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure should be:

```
llvm/
  projects/
    compiler-rt/
    libcxx/
    libcxxabi/
  tools/
    clang/
```

I'm not sure how far along libc++ support for Windows is, as I just use MSVC's implementation for ABI compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling llvm framework (llvm, clang, libc++, etc...) with Visual Studio 2013 is not so dificult.

1. Download the sources
2. Descompress the sources
3. Move the decompressed folders to their place in the llvm source tree. (ex: cfe-version goes in `llvm\tools` directory with name clang. This king of info could be obtained from the CMakeFile.txt files (ex: `add_llvm_external_project(clang)` in the file `llvm\tools\CMakeFile.txt). The CMakeFile.txt are the files that instruct [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) program how to generate the projects (ex: Makefile, VS projects, XCode projects... for compile llvm)
4. Create a directory where to save the vs2013 projects
5. Generate the VS2013 projects (ex: being inside the previous directory execute: `cmake llvm_sources -G "Visual Studio 12"` where llvm_sources is the root directory of the llvm sources.
6. Open the project and compile (could take long to compile 30min or more)

Notes: some projects (ex: lldb) could need additional dependencies (ex: python c headers for bindings).

One of the problems of clang when compiling from sources is that the directory path of the include headers that clang use (ex: std library headers), are fixed in the source code in: `llvm\tools\clang\lib\FrontEnd\InitHeaderSearch.cpp`, in the case of compiling llvm with VS2013, by default it use the MS std headers.

Compiling almost every mid size program with clang using the MS header would give you error with MS extensions not supported yet by clang, with non-conforming c++ (that vc++ accept as valid) and other sort of problems, this is the case of various libraries of boost also (when using the MS headers).

Better success history for me was compile using this same procedure with MinGW for windows and using the MinGW headers. In this case most probably need to modify by hand the HeaderSearch file for clang to search for the header (the last versions of clang don't have search path for the last versions of gcc, at least in the stable version 3.5.0).

Using this method, I successfully compile clang 3.5.0 with MinGW with GCC 4.9.1 in Windows 8.1.

Comment: clang does support MS extensions and non-conforming C++ required to compile MSVC headers. You just need to enable the support by either using clang-cl.exe or by setting the target `-target i686-pc-windows-msvc`. Exceptions are not supported yet, so you need to also set `-D_HAS_EXCEPTION=0`.

Comment: Yes, it support some extensions (late compilation of templates, predefined macros of vc++, etc...), but far, from all the extensions used in MS headers (probably stl library is OK, i have seen some examples using DX compiling, but in `Windows.h`, `MFC`, etc... you most certain would find problems), because of this problems is that `clang-cl.exe` have a fallback mode, when it can't compile the code (it passes to VC++ `cl.exe`)

Comment: Oh, yeah, MFC and the like may still be broken. I was only thinking of programs limited to standard and Win32 headers (e.g., Windows.h works for me). I was also just able to compile and run a program using `<Audioclient.h> <atlbase.h> <audiopolicy.h> <mmdeviceapi.h>` (clang++, not clang-cl and I didn't use /fallback). I don't use and don't have any MFC code to try.

Comment: I will need to test again, thx. Do you use the pre-build Clang of the site, compiled from sources with VS2013 or with MinGW?

Comment: I build clang from source (daily, from the trunk) with VS2013.

Comment: Thx very much. Probably is that, I only use stable versions (now 3.5.0).

Comment: If clang need to built from source , then VS community or express edition is needed? I tried with express edition from so many days , nothing working.